# Donation amount into QuickBooks Nonprofit Thank You

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, quickbooks

I am trying to do what I think should be an easy operation in QuickBooks Premier (NonProfit Edition) 2015.  The software has a very nice feature for sending Thank You letters to donors.  It is accessed from the menus by going to:

> Nonprofit > Send Letters to Your Donors > Prepare customer letters
>   with envelopes > (Select a Donor) > Nonprofit Thank You (under Choose
>   a Letter Template, Letter template available for customers/jobs)

The problem I'm having is that there does not appear to be a way to insert the donation amount into the letter template.  If I edit the letter template by going to:

> Nonprofit > Send Letters to Your Donors > Prepare customer letters
>   with envelopes > (Select a Donor) > Create or Edit a letter template >
>   View or Edit Existing Letter Templates > Customer > Nonprofit Thank
>   You

Then Microsoft Word will open and allow me to edit the template.  From within Word under the **ADD-INS** Menu I am presented with two custom QuickBooks drop-down menus that will insert QuickBooks letter template variables into my letter template document.  My choices of fields are from two categories:

1. "Insert My Company Fields" - Contains template variables related to
   my company
2. "Insert Customer Name Fields" - Contains template variables related
   to the customer (Donor)

Unfortunately no field under the "Insert Customer Name Fields" allows me to choose a donation amount.

I am aware that there are other reports in QuickBooks that I can use to show the amount.  Is the intention that I have to create both a letter and the separate report and attach both for my donors?  Is there not a way to send a single letter that shows the amount?

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using the approach I was trying.  I was, however, able to achieve what I wanted another way as explained here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXkWNFuWX3Q

And to get the name field to show up, on the original Sales Receipt screen under the Donor box it shows their name and address (I added their name to the customer address field) and in the Ship To box I put the customer name only.  Then I added a "Dear " text field and a Data Field for "Ship To" right after it in order to make it say "Dear Name" in my sales receipt form.  It's working for now, even though there may be a better to do it.